# Issue in File exporter while trying to export the documents

Tags: data-export

I am trying to export the contents from a salesforce org using file exporter.

I have installed Data loader 21.

After running the file exporter.bat:
2 folders created:
1. CSVs 2. Exported content
CSVs folder has 4 files: ContentVersion.FileType.csv,ContentVersion.FirstPublishLocationId.csv,ContentVersion.Title &ContentVersion.VersionData.

In the exported content all the files are exported but the size is 0.

In the file exporter console window i see the msg:

"A duplicate file name exists , or the file cannot be found"

Now the issue is I am all the files but the size is o for all files.

Can anyone faces similar issue, can anyone suggest any solutions. Appreciate your help and support on this.